# Semantic Segmentation using Scipy or Scikit-image

Tags: image-recognition, opencv, scipy

Many days ago I saw a user using scipy function to get region of interest (RoI) in an image using different colors. I believe it was some sort of filter. Now I'm trying to do the same but I'm not able to find that content anymore.

I would grateful if you could help me with that problem.

Image Example: [Example of Semantic Segmentation](https://paperswithcode.com/media/thumbnails/task/task-0000000885-88f43a92.jpg)